# How to link to a taxonomy term of a view?

Tags: views, 8, theming

I would like to add a link in my template to the view page "taxonomy term", for a term of taxonomy to partiluer.

For example, in my taxonomy "thing" I have the term "truc", and I would like the link redirect to the page of the term taxonomy "truc".

I tried `<a href="{{ path('view.taxonomy_term.page_1') }}">{{ 'Name'|t }}</a>` but of course it does not work because I do not know where to put the term in question (in example the term "truc").

Do you know how to do it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one

```
<a href="{{ path('entity.taxonomy_term.canonical', {'taxonomy_term' => term_id}) }}">{{ 'Name'|t }}</a>
```

Where term_id is your taxonomy term id.